# How to emit data from socket-IO client to socket-IO server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

so I am developing an small application that need a bi-directional channel to transmit data between client and server.

I have no problem to send sata from server to client. Works just fine. But , the other way around is not working. for some reason , sending data from client to client does not work.

here is the client.js

```
let io = require('socket.io-client');
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000/", {
    reconnection: false
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected to server');
    socket.emit('data', 'data is emitted !')
});
```

and here is server.js :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(process.env.port||5000);

io.on('connection',function () {
    console.log('client connected');

    io.on('data',function (data) {
        console.log(`data received is '${data}'`)
    })

});
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server code needs to listen for incoming events from a particular `socket.on()`, not `io.on()`.  `io` is the server.  It gets notified of new connections, but not of individual messages on a given connection.  You have to listen to events on a particular socket to receive data from the client.

So, change to this (change `io` to `socket` in one place and add `socket` argument to the `io.on('connection', function(socket) ());` handler (see the two places that `socket` was added below):

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(process.env.port||5000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('client connected');

    // listen for incoming data msg on this newly connected socket
    socket.on('data',function (data) {
        console.log(`data received is '${data}'`)
    });

});
```

Note: the addition of `socket` in two places.

Comment: Okay it does work ... Quick explanation through : where was I wrong ?

Comment: @wawa - Do you see the `io.on()` in your code that I changed to a `socket.on()`?  And the addition of the `socket` parameter to the `io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... })` handler?

Comment: ahhhhh ! yes ! okay got it. Thanks for your help ! But what is the difference between io and socket ?